# Discord.py printing out random choice

Tags: python, discord.py

Im playing with my own casino discord bot and i am setting up using Python. Im still really new to python and i have this little snippet working. I went to make it so the if you win or lose the bot will print out what random choice it chose into the discord text chat.

Unfortunatley ive been reading and looking and trying to figure this out but i keep running into a bot crash.

Can anyone show or enlighten me on how i can properly make the bot print to discord?
You Picked: {Your Choice}, I Rolled {Bot Roll Choice}

```
async def roll(
        self,
        ctx: commands.Context,
        choice: int,
        bet: int=DEFAULT_BET
    ):
        self.check_bet(ctx, bet)
        choices = range(1,7) #Picking number between 1-6
        value = random.choice(choices) #Print Bot choice Value for user
        if choice in choices:
            if random.choice(choices) == choice: #If User Choice == User Choice
                await ctx.send('You Picked: '+choice+' I Rolled: '+{value})#If win print chat and tell user bot choice.
                self.economy.add_money(ctx.author.id, bet*6)#add money to user account
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

# Instantiate your bot
```

Do `@bot.command` if it says `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')` where you defined your `commands.Bot` instance, like me; but if it says `client = commands.Bot(...)`, then do `@client.command` instead.

```
@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx, guess, moneyamount):
    random_num = random.randint(1,6) # Returns a random integer from 1 to 6
    if guess > 6:
        await ctx.send('Please choose a number between 6!')
    elif guess == random_num:
        pass
        # The user guessed it correctly
        # Do what you want to do here
    else:
        await ctx.send("That wasn't the correct number.")
```

The pass means you do what you want there, like if you add money or subtract.

So the full code should look like this:

```
import random

# Bot setup 

@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx, guess, moneyamount):
    random_num = random.randint(1,6)
    if guess > 6:
        await ctx.send('Please choose a number between 6!')
    elif guess == random_num:
        pass
        # ...
    else:
        await ctx.send("That wasn't the correct number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution to your problem.

I think that `random.randint(1, 7)` would be the best option for generating your number (don't forget to import **`random`**).

In terms of "printing" to discord, you can just do something along the lines of:

```py
await ctx.send(f"You picked {choice}. I rolled {value}")
```

So all together this should work:

```py
async def roll(ctx, bet): # get the user's "bet".
#I assume you don't want bets to be higher than 6. 
#So check if the bet is higher than 6
if bet is > 6: 
  await ctx.send(f"Bet's can only be between 1 & 6")
else: 
  # Now we need to get the bot to pick its number and see if it matches the bet. 
  choice = random.randint(1, 7)
  if choice == bet:  
     await ctx.send(f"Congarts you won.\n**The winning bet:** `{bet}`")
  else: 
     await ctx.send(f"You picked {bet} however I rolled {choice}")
```

This code should pick a random number between 1 & 6 and then compare that to the user's bet. If the user's bet matches the random number then the bot will say "congrats you won". However, if the bet doesn't match the bot's choice then the bot will display both the bet and the choice.

**Note:**
The [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module is needed for this code to work